Issue with GraphicsLayer Modifier in ViewPager2 Fragments Using Jetpack Compose
I'm working on an Android project that uses ViewPager2 to host fragments, each containing a view with Jetpack Compose at its root. In these Compose views, I'm applying a Modifier.graphicsLayer that takes a lambda as a parameter to perform translations on the view.
The problem I'm facing is that when I switch fragments in the ViewPager2, the lambda function passed to the graphicsLayer modifier is no longer called. This results in the translations not being applied as expected when I navigate back to a fragment.
Here is a simplified version of my setup:
@Composable
fun MyComposeView() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer {
                translationX = // some calculation
                translationY = // some calculation
            }
    ) {
        // Content
    }
}

In my fragment:
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyComposeView()
            }
        }
    }
}

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on why the lambda in the graphicsLayer modifier is not being called after fragment changes? Any suggestions on how to ensure the lambda continues to be invoked when the fragment is revisited?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Here a sample -> https://github.com/BenjaminBihr/Sample/tree/main
